# int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter -- delete local file if not valid

Tags: spring-integration

I am using int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter to download valid files from sftp server to local dir. I need to delete local file if that file is rejected by my custom filter. Is this something achieved via config or need to implement code? If so is there any sample out there?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do the deletion in your custom filter. Use `File.delete()`.

But, of course, it would be better to use a custom remote filter, instead of a custom local filter, to avoid fetching the invalid file (unless you need to look at the contents).